# Nginx not Caching my Application

Tags: node.js, express, caching, nginx

I'm trying to setup the caching of my ExpressApp and its rendered Jade files with Nginx.

When I have a look at the pm2 logs of my application while running the google Pagespeed Insight test, I see that the Images and HTML are still served by the app instead of the Nginx proxy.

Two Questions:

1. How do I have to change my configuration to have the desired effect?
2. How do I effectively validate that the Setup/Caching is working?

Thanks!

#### My current Nginx Configuration:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=backcache:8m max_size=50m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {

                 expires 1w;
                 proxy_cache backcache;
                 #proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
                 add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

                 proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
         } 
}
```

## Headers:

```
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: ###
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
* Server certificate: AddTrust External CA Root
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ###
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 13:15:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 66761
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, x-access-token, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, un-populated
< ETag: W/"104c9-8+4lo531tUk9k3SJq4sPHg"
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 13:15:37 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
```

## Headers of two consecutive Requests to an Image

```
➜  ~ curl -I **url/img.jpg**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 03:17:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 11007
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, x-access-token, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, un-populated
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 16:23:13 GMT
ETag: W/"2aff-158731964ca"
Expires: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 03:17:02 GMT
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS

➜  ~ curl -I **url/img.jpg**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 03:17:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 11007
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, x-access-token, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, un-populated
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 16:23:13 GMT
ETag: W/"2aff-158731964ca"
Expires: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 03:17:08 GMT
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
```

Comment: To debug this it would be helpful if you could post the request and response headers of two subsequent requests to the same resource. Make sure that the browser is not set to disable caching.

Comment: @Digitalkapitaen Thanks for your Reply! Added the Headers accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The headers you show as the request headers are most probably not the original ones, because it says "Provisional headers shown".

The actual request headers probably contain the "cache-control" header and your nginx configuration uses that header to bypass the cache, as indicated by the 'X-Proxy-Cache:BYPASS' response header.

If there is no reason to keep it, you should remove the `proxy_cache_bypass`-directive from your config.

Comment: I removed the proxy_cache_bypass, thanks. When I watch my pm2 logs from the express application and run the googleopagespeed test, I see how every request comes in and is still handled by express. Ideally nginx would serve these files from Cache. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, can you post the full headers? You can get them with `curl -v http://example.com/ -o /dev/null`.

Comment: Edited the Headers, better this way? @Digitalkapitaen

Comment: Looks like i have a proxy-cache HIT on the html files, but an MISS on the img-files. Same "location" though...

Comment: The header you posted indicates that nginx does not have the file in its cache. What happens when you execute the curl again? Then it should come from the cache and not hit you backend. 

Also for the images, best is to post the headers of two subsequent requests,  because the reason for caching/not caching should be in there.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Attached the two Requests to the image-file. Any Idea? @Digitalkapitaen

Comment: I have no idea. The headers you show are exactly the same, so nginx should cache. Maybe there is something in the request headers. You could also try to send a request to your node app directly and see if there are any problematic headers.